# How can i show image carousel on every view in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application where i am using the image carousel on the recyclerview. I have many products to show in recycler view with title and price and multiple images in carousel. How can i acheive that. in the recyler view how can i set the images on the bind viewholder. please guide me

**like this**
[image]

Comment: Give it a try https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview

Comment: or this https://github.com/jama5262/CarouselView

Comment: brother thank you for this but can you tell me how can i set this carosuel on my recyclerview??

Comment: you can add this view in your item and then set it in adapter